# Unable to get the content out of a HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm trying to get the contents of a HttpServletRequest. Here is how I'm doing it:

```
// Extract the request content
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
String content = "";

try {
    InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
    if (inputStream != null) {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
            stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    } else {
        stringBuilder.append("");
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    throw ex;
} finally {
    if (bufferedReader != null) {
        try {
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}

content =  stringBuilder.toString();
System.out.println("Length: " + request.getContentLength());
```

The String "content" is empty. However, the last line displays

> Length: 53

which is exactly the length of the content I'm expecting. If it helps, here is how I trigger this servlet:

```
wget --post-data='{"imei":"351553012623446","hni":"310150","wdp":false}' http://localhost:8080/test/forward
```

Comment: What servlet container are you using?  Your code works for me in Tomcat 6.0.18.

Comment: Tomcat 6.0.20
So you are getting something in "content"?

Comment: How are you verifying the value of "content"?

Comment: @pensador yes, I added System.out.println("content==" + content) to your code and I see the post data from wget.

Comment: @Jack Leow: I tried both running the server in debug mode & inspecting "content" and displaying it on the console with System.out.println().

@John Wagenleitner: Any idea as to what could be wrong on my side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally found the answer! Turns out that the value of "post-data" that is given to wget becomes the name of a parameter in the request. In other words, if I get the parameter name of the first (and only) parameter in the request, I will get that value. The code to extract it is trivial:

```
// Extract the post content from the request
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Enumeration<String> paramEnum = request.getParameterNames();
paramEnum.hasMoreElements();
String postContent = (String) paramEnum.nextElement();
```

Thanks everyone for your responses!